# Pktgen fails to compile - Error: include ‘<ctype.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘isspace’ / ’isblank’

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, dpdk

I'm trying to compile pktgen, but keep getting this error when I try to compile:

[image: pktgen]

The DPDK version I'm running is `dpdk-stable-22.11.1` and I'm following the official guide *[Getting Started with Pktgen](https://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)* and I get the error message after I have `cd` into the pktgen repo and run `make`. Before that I have run the following in the `dpdk-stable-22.11.1` directory.

```
  meson build
  ninja -C build
```

I have also setup hugepages.

The error seems to suggest there is something wrong with the code inside of Pktgen which seems unlikely. When I go into the file `pg_strings.c` and include `ctype.h`, then run `make` again, it does not give me an error for those files anymore but instead find some issue within another file etc. So it seems like something is very wrong. Any ideas on what might be the cause of this?

I'm also running this in Virtualbox with Ubuntu 22.04 if that is relevant for the issue.

UPDATE:

To clarify if I include `ctype.h` I get a new error which says:

[image: new error]

And if I fix this error I come to another file where I have to fix another error and so on. Therefore, I cannot simply include `ctype`.

Comment: In the upstream sources, the fix was to add the line `#include <ctype.h>` after the `#include <arpa/inet.h>` in "lib/common/pg_strings.h".

Comment: If I fix this error I come to another file where I have to fix another error etc. and I don't know when it will ever stop coming new errors. Therefore, I don't think the solution is to include #include <ctype.h> @IanAbbott

Comment: Perhaps you should build the development version from the git repository then, or wait for the next stable release.

Comment: I tried to build on the dev branch but it did not work either unfortunately @IanAbbott

Comment: @Agentsmith2.0, you appear to be building with the `-Werror` compiler option, or perhaps some specific `-Werror=` options.  You could perhaps get a successful build (albeit still with warnings) by turning those off.  HOWEVER, having warnings / errors such as those is a red flag even if you do get a successful build, so if you can't wait for a new stable release then you might want to substitute an altogether different component, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the issues related to using pktgen 22.04.01 with the latest DPDK 22.11.1 are referenced (indirectly, of course) in the DPDK release file, which can be found at doc/guides/rel_notes/release_22_11.rst (or [here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/rel_notes/release_22_11.html))

The main issue appears to be how they've reworked their BUS / PCI libraries, and correspondingly the headers.

There are two things you'll have to do differently than the basic setup steps:

1. build DPDK with the `enable_driver_sdk` option, e.g.:

```bash
    meson -Dexamples=all -Denable_driver_sdk=true build
    ninja -C build
    sudo ninja install
```

`-Dexamples=all` isn't necessary, but gives you the example programs.  The crucial part is the `-Denable_driver_sdk=true`, which will add capability and install a few header files that wouldn't exist otherwise, e.g. bus_driver.h

2. Update their pktgen code so it compiles:

- lib/common/pg_strings.h:  **add** `#include <ctype.h>`
- app/pktgen-port-cfg.h:  **comment out** the line `{RTE_ETH_RX_OFFLOAD_HEADER_SPLIT, _(HEADER_SPLIT)},`  (It may be the case that `RTE_ETH_RX_OFFLOAD_HEADER_SPLIT` could simply be substituted with `RTE_ETH_RX_OFFLOAD_BUFFER_SPLIT`, but that may be an incomplete fix.  If you plan to offload RX header splitting to the hardware, you'll want to make sure this is properly working)
- app/pktgen-port-cfg.c:  **comment out** `.split_hdr_size = 0`
- every file with `#include <rte_bus_pci.h>` (app/pktgen-latency.c, app/pktgen-port-cfg.c, app/pktgen-stats.c, app/pktgen-rate.c, app/lpktgenlib.c):  **add** the following:

```c
    #include <rte_bus.h>
    #include <bus_pci_driver.h>
    #include <bus_driver.h>
```

Comment: Perhaps this works but I get "No such file or directory" for #include <bus_pci_driver.h> and #include <bus_driver.h>

Comment: @Agentsmith2.0 I would double-check that you did step 1, since that is where those files get installed (specifically, with the -Denable_driver_sdk=true option)

Comment: In app/lpktgenlib.c add `#include <rte_bus.h>  #include <bus_pci_driver.h>   #include <bus_driver.h>` (on different lines, of course)